# PHP Cast to my class

Tags: php, casting

why this is not possible:

```
$user = (User) $u[0];
```

but this is possible

```
$bool = (boolean) $res['success'];
```

I use PHP 7.0.

Comment: Casting to object is unsafe. Why do you want to do so? Not sure if it's relevant, you can use `instanceof` to check the class of the object.

Comment: What is `$u[0]`?

Comment: as i know, you can only cast do primitive data types see [Type Casting] http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: yea php does not support implicit conversion like C# does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As I know, in PHP you can only cast to some types:

```
(int), (integer) - cast to integer
(bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
(float), (double), (real) - cast to float  (real deprecated in PHP 8.0)
(string) - cast to string
(binary) - cast to binary string (PHP 6)
(array) - cast to array
(object) - cast to object
(unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5) (depracted in PHP 7.2) (removed in 8.0)
```

(see [Type Casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php))

Instead you could use [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php) to check of specific type:

```
if($yourvar instanceof YourClass) {
    //DO something
} else {
    throw new Exception('Var is not of type YourClass');
}
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned by Szabolcs Páll in his answer, it is also possible to declare a [return type](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_returntype_declarations.htm) or [parameter type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php), but in that cases an exception ([TypeError](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php)) will be throwen, if the type does not match.

```
function test(): string
{
    return 'test';
}

function test(string $test){
    return "test" . $test;
}
```

Since PHP 7.2 it is also possible to make the types nullable by adding ? in front of them:

```
function test(): ?string
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 58):

You can use PHPDoc

```
/** @var User $user */
$user = $u[0];
```

Comment: Yes, casting to class in PHP has only it's purpose when used for IDE autocomplete/suggestions. So PHPDoc is the way to go. You can even simplify it by writing just /** @var User */ without variable name.

Comment: This is assuming that you're just trying to add a type hint for static analysis. A runtime cast/assertion is more useful for preventing errors, and the runtime cast/assertion will inherently bring along the "compile-time" information if you're using a static analysis tool that's even halfway decent.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want to ensure a variable is instance of YourClass and let exception handling to the typesystem you can use the following function:

```
function implicitFakeCast($myClass): YourClass
{
    return $myClass;
}
```

**Note:** this will not actually do any casting, rather it throws exceptions in case of class mismatch and lets intellisense treat it as an instance of the target class.

Comment: Exceptions should be used to handle **exceptions** occuring under **exceptional** circumstances, and not as a routine method of program logic or performing tests.

Comment: Totally agree, and indeed having an unexpected class as a return value of a function/method can be just as exceptional as trying to cast the uncastable.

Comment: Code that has type errors should certainly be considered `exceptional`.

Comment: I came up with this as well. `$class = Derived::class; $instance =  self::castAsBaseAbstract(new $class()); ... private static function castAsBaseAbstract($object): BaseAbstract{ return $object; }`. Although this is a great solution, it's easier to use phpDoc as suggested by @adir-kandel. The concept of exceptions with this isn't really important. This is entirely to get the benefits of intellisense. My use case has the class types in an array and instances being created in a loop. All instances derive from the same base class.

Answer (score 11):

For people that do want to be able to cast to a class type. I've found a gist by @borzilleri that uses serialize and unserialize to achieve this: https://gist.github.com/borzilleri/960035.

**TL;DR:**

```
// make sure to include the namespace when casting
$className = "Some\\NameSpace\\SomeClassName";
$classNameLength = strlen( $className );
$castedItem = unserialize(
    preg_replace(
        '/^O:\d+:"[^"]++"/',
        "O:$classNameLength:\"$className\"",
        serialize( $item )
    )
)
```

Comment: What a dirty hack! Love this :)

Answer (score 9):

It's really simple in php8:

```
 $item = (fn($item):YourClass=>$item)($item);
```

Comment: This code does nothing if `$item` is an instance of `YourClass`, otherwise it will throw a type error.

Comment: Yes, that is the point! BUT, it makes sure that your instance is `YourClass`, and as side effect, the IDE (phpstorm) will know it... (without any ugly annotations...). This is almost the same solution provided by @szabolcs-páll above, but with the php8 arrow function, as an inline solution...

Comment: Love this solution, thanks! Just fyi, this works as of PHP 7.4 https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

Comment: Very intuitive!

Comment: For clarity: If the type of `$item` is `object` then this gives a TypeError. It does not cast or change the type of the object.

Comment: Useful when you implement a method (for instance `calculate()`) in a processor class (for instance MexicoCalculator) that inherits from a superclass (for instance CountryCalculator) that gets a generic parameter (for example CountryParameters) and you want to treat it like specific parameters like for exemple MexicoParameters. In the `MexicoCalculator::calculate()` you need to receive a `MexicoParameters` that is received like `CountryCalculator` and you want to treat it specific-wise, not generic-wise. This "forces" similarly to the old-style `if()` where you check the class.

Answer (score 3):

Objects and primitive types are different. Since it's called as primitive types, they are really simple, maybe only 1 byte, 2 bytes, or 4 bytes, and at most 8 bytes.

When we are talking about object, this object can have different attributes with the others. Then the question from PHP will be is, "is this object really from my Class?" "How to convert this object to my Class?". Thus, you can't parse right away the object using

```
$myObject = (ClassName) $variable
```

Then how to cast it? Dunno, but usually the approach is like this:

1. Create constructor for the class
2. In the class, make a method that specifically accept certain parameters, maybe array

here is sample:

```
public class MyAwesomeClass{


     function __construct($thisIsArray){
         $this->attributeA = $thisIsArray["A"];
         $this->attributeB = $thisIsArray["B"];
         ......
     }

     static function fromArray($thisIsArray){
         return MyAwesomeClass($thisIsArray);
     }

}

$obj = MyAwesomeClass::fromArray($attributes);
```

Comment: Wish PHP will somehow offer the `.` syntax. However, until that happens, you ment `$obj = MyAwesomeClass::fromArray($attributes);`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer on why this is not possible, I would suggest that you write a builder function that creates an object, based on your input. so it would look something like

```
$user = User::buildFromSomeArrayInput($u[0]);
```

And then have a builder create a new `User` object, assign the right properties, etc. You could just do all this in-place of course, but having a builder function makes sure you won't be doing this on several locations, AND you can set private properties as it is a class-member function. It is a bit more work then having it magically work, but not that much.
The only issue you might have is when you do have a different object that does not expose all the internals you might need. But this is for a reason, as internals might change -> you don't want to rely on that.

There are hacks out there that suggest doing this with serialization. I would suggest to steer away from them, as they are hackish and as far as i'm concerned, not very clear.