# In PHP 8.1, is there a more concise way to define the variable type than using @var?

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have the following line of code in a test (this is from Laravel)

```
$eyepieceLine = EyepieceLine::factory()->create();
```

The `factory()->create()` is a Laravel internal thing and I cannot control the return type of `create()`.

However, the thing it returns adheres to an interface and I only care about the interface for the purpose of the rest of the test.

What I currently need to do is this:

```
/** @var EyepieceLineInterface $eyepieceLine */
$eyepieceLine = EyepieceLine::factory()->create();
```

This is quite verbose, ugly, and takes up more space than it should (imagine several such lines of code for different entities).

Does PHP have the ability to type hint in-line, like other languages?

E.g:

```
EyepieceLineInterface $eyepieceLine = EyepieceLine::factory()->create();
```

Comment: unfortunatey, there is no possibility to type variables in PHP and i did not see any RFC for this functionnality so it does not seem to be planned

Comment: Maybe casting to the class `EyepieceLineInterface` would help: [PHP Cast to my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623498/php-cast-to-my-class).